# How to uninstall NetBeans 8.1's Tomcat and GlassFish?

Tags: uninstall, security, netbeans, tomcat, glassfish

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 with GNOME 3.20 (though I was running 15.10 when I installed it) and when I installed NetBeans 8.1 I selected to install Tomcat and GlassFish as well which seem to be located in `/usr/local` as far as I can tell along with NetBeans. NetBeans also seems to be quite interconnected with them so I would probably have to do at least part of the uninstallation through NetBeans or would have to do quite a lot of tweaking to cleanly remove them.

But as I don't have a real use for them and security updates keep being released for Tomcat, but even though there is a bugzilla report open on this matter, they haven't backported in a Tomcat update in ages so I am rather worried on the security front.

So is there any way to uninstall Tomcat and GlashFish? I have checked and it did not install the packages from the repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to uninstall these components you will need go into the directories in which they are installed in `/usr/local` (or wherever you install NetBeans to, if `sudo` is not used during the installation then it is likely to be `~`) and execute the `uninstall.sh` files:

```
sudo uninstall.sh
```

This should launch the NetBeans installer which you should select the `Uninstall` option on. This will completely remove the components you run the `uninstall.sh` files for.